# An up to date Quickly(ubuntu) Guide

Tags: python, pygtk, ubuntu-11.04, canonical-quickly

Does anyone know of an up to date guide for Quickly, it has changed a lot since I have lasted used it.

I'm trying to link a button to an function. I believe all you need to do is name the function in a special way ([buttonname]_clicked_event).

Thanks
Sam

Comment: Maybe you could move this question to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or try to ask directly in [launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/quickly).